# How to create the effect on web page for selecting part of text by jquery

Tags: jquery, effect, side-effects

How can I create effect(by jquery) in web page when user select a part of text then focus paragraph and dark other part of page?
How can create this effect?
For example can see [this link](http://www.pixeler.ir/%D8%AA%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%BE%D9%88%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%81%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%B1-%D8%AA%D8%A7-%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%81/)

this image show the web page before select the text(top of image) and when select a part of text bye mouse cursor(bottom of image):
[view image](http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/08/17/select_text3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS transitions and JQuery

here is my solution with using of css transition and jquery

```
a {
  color:blue;
  /* First we need to help some browsers along for this to work.
     Just because a vendor prefix is there, doesn't mean it will
     work in a browser made by that vendor either, it's just for
     future-proofing purposes I guess. */
  -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
  /* ...and now for the proper property */
  transition:color .2s ease-out, background 2s ease-in;
}
```

edited [DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/6unwup99/1/)